# Upgrade to 18.04 from 16.04: cannot boot into desktop

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, nouveau

Have an older Dell Inspirion 5720 that I just upgraded to 18.04...

When the machine rebooted, it basically goes into an endless wait state:  the GUI never loads and if I flip around on the terminals, I see the error message:

nouveau: .... MMIO write of 00000001f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
A start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up (no limit)

I can ssh into the box, and dmsg shows this:

```
[    1.755073] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 1024 MiB GDDR5
[    1.761716] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: volt: couldn't find speedo value, volting not possible
[    1.761769] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 612004 [ IBUS ]
...
[   26.653007] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000001f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[   37.565957] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000001f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
```

With the last two messages repeating...

I've tried blacklisting the nouveau drivers from the kernel by adding a blacklist directive into a new .conf file in /etc/modprobe.d and specifying that nouveau never is loaded again by aliasing it to /bin/false in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

I also tried adding "nomodeset" to GRUB bootloader and rebooting, but no love at all.

Here's all the related output from journalctl -b:

```
root@mongoid:/home/mshallop# journalctl -b | grep nouveau
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GF117 (0d7000a2)
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 75.17.33.00.01
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 1024 MiB GDDR5
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: volt: couldn't find speedo value, volting not possible
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 612004 [ IBUS ]
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 1024 MiB
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table invalid
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY0 for buffer copies
Nov 12 12:39:46 mongoid kernel: [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid sensors[886]: nouveau-pci-0100
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[999]: (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[999]: (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[999]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[999]: (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[999]: (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.3.1
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of ffffff1f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of badf1001 FAULT at 50405c [ IBUS ]
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[999]: (II) NOUVEAU(G0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: nouveau
Nov 12 12:39:48 mongoid /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[999]: (II) NOUVEAU(G0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nouveau
Nov 12 12:40:02 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000001f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
Nov 12 12:40:13 mongoid kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000001f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
```

How do I disable this (or better, remove) this mod that's dorking my system?

Thanks!

Comment: `nomodeset` should be enough to load a default desktop with decreased resolution but allowing you to install/reinstall the recommended Nvidia drivers needed for your graphics. But I'm not sure about what you did before as it may have created a different conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try blacklisting nouveau completely:

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and finally reboot the system.

you might also try running the following command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: thanks for the answer - I was forgetting the update-initramfs directive... ugh... once I was able to boot, I forced an update and then updated again... I'm cleanly booting into the 4.15 kernel... now I need to unscrew the other box the 18.04 update messed up there, too...

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my drive. I got nothing after booting but this two lines with a black background:

```
[    5.885218] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: NNIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 612004 [ IBUS ]
[    5.885223] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: volt: couldn't find speedo value, volting not possible
```

I thought that it was maybe the problem of not removing the USB stick the good time, so installed it again, with exact same settings. Same issue.

Searching on the Internet, people are talking about NVIDIA drivers causing the issue (hinted by the word nouveau). It happens that I have an NVIDIA card. So, I was wondering why would a fresh install have any of the NVIDIA drivers, because as I remember, I always had to install it after the operating system was up and running.

I installed the OS with

- Download updates while installing Ubuntu **checked**
- Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware, Flash, MP3 and other media **unchecked**

Then I thought that I would give it a try with **both unchecked** (UNchecked), and having every other settings the same way. I don't know if this has **FIXED** the issue, the only thing I know is that now I don't get the error and the system boots perfectly.

Hope it helps anybody.

Comment: I tried both unchecked as well. It didn't solve the issue for me.